# Integrate vue-gtm with unhead

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, unheadvue

I'm using [@unhead/vue](https://unhead.unjs.io/) to manage changing page titles and meta tags in a VueJS3 SPA.  I'd like to use [@gtm-support/vue-gtm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gtm-support/vue-gtm) to handle my GTM tagging and events.

My setup:

```js
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createHead } from '@unhead/vue';
import { createGtm } from '@gtm-support/vue-gtm';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(createHead());
app.use(
  createGtm({
    id: 'GTM-XXXXXXXX',
    vueRouter: router,
    debug: true,
  }),
);

app.mount('#app');
```

I have a dynamic route `/go/:name` that has a different page `<title>` depending on the value of `:name`.  This is set in the component like so:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useHead } from '@unhead/vue';
const route = useRoute();
const name = route.params.name;

useHead({
  title: `Go to ${name}`,
});
```

Currently, with `debug: true` on in my vue-gtm config, I see events like this:

```
{screenName: 'go', path: '/go/foo'}
{screenName: 'go', path: '/go/bar'}
{screenName: 'go', path: '/go/qua'}
```

How can I change the screenName being sent to be different on each of those pages, ideally picking up the value I'm already setting in the title with unhead?